# What's the meaning of "you're supposed to"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the meaning of
 "you're supposed to"?
For example:

> "You're supposed to stop when at a red light."
>   "You're supposed to unpack once you get there."

Comment: It roughly means "You're expected to ...". If you like something even simpler, you could read it (approximately) as "You should ...".

Comment: You might wish to note that the *origin* of this particular usage has been covered on ELU, where [the very highly-rated top answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/21852/2637) starts off by saying *This is a complicated issue, and one that is still not fully understood by linguists*. The answer is quite long, and makes no concessions to non-native speakers, but it's also very interesting if you can manage to follow it.

Answer (score 7):

When you're supposed to do something, you're expected or required to do something. In your example sentences:

*"You're supposed to stop when at a red light"* carries with it a variety of meanings and implications: "You are expected to stop", "According to the rules of the road, you must stop", "The police may catch you if you do not stop"

*"You're supposed to unpack once you get there."* means someone wants you to unpack once you arrive at your destination - it might be the person speaking (your parent?), the person on-site (the camp counselor?).

*"Supposed to"* can also be used when you talk about general rules of good behaviour, health & safety, or common sense, for instance:

- *"In the old days, men were supposed to stand up when a woman wanted to leave the table."*
- *"You're supposed to wash your hands after you've used the toilet."*
- *"You're supposed to recycle as much plastic as possible."*

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way:

When we want to give advice to anybody for anything when that person is older than us.
We use "You're supposed to+verb+other words" instead of "Should".
We use "Should" to any person who is younger than us.